# Get components from custom attributes with vue?

Tags: vue.js

Im usign vue js for validate form before submit.
This code start a new Vue getting data from the `ID = app`:

```
  const app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
      text: null
    }
```

I want create a custom attribute named `form-number` and get data usign my
attribute and not the div.

Example:

Change this

```
<form id="app" method="post">
    <input type="text" v-model='text'>
</form>
```

For this

```
<form form-number="1" method="post">
    <input type="text" v-model='text'>
</form>

  const app = new Vue({
    el:"form-number='1'",
    data:{
      text: null
    }
```

Comment: I don't really get what you're after - you don't need that with a proper **Vue** form. Maybe if you shared your app (HTML, CSS, JS), then it would be more understandable.

Comment: @muka.gergely Hi, I dont want get data using a id, I want set a custom attribute named form-number and get the data from that attribute and not from the id

Comment: @muka.gergely Please see my updated question

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think you either do not share some information (not on purpose, of course), or do not really grasped how a **Vue** app should look like and work. Most of the time, you don't read anything from DOM elements - no attributes, no content, nothing. The app controls all the data, so it does not need to read the tags. But anyways, I try to formulate an answer based on the info you gave.

Comment: @muka.gergely I don't share more code because this is an example :), right now I try delete the ID and try get data with my custom attribute for ontinue with the code, Thanks!

Comment: The snippet is ready - I hope it clears up things a bit. With **Vue** you should start to forget the DOM. Most of the time you will only need it to display something - not store data for you (for your app). Sorry if my previous comment was a bit rough, didn't mean to hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Vue** the template is not to be read - inputs are possible through bindings (like `v-model`).

See this snippet:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  data: {
    formNumber: 1,
    text: ''
  }
})

app.$mount('[myCustomAttribute="mounthere"]')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div myCustomAttribute="mounthere">
  <form :form-number="formNumber" method="post">
    <label for="text1">
      From{{ formNumber }} input:
    <input id="text1" type="text" v-model="text" />
    </label>
  </form>
  {{ text }}
</div>
```

`formNumber` is also defined in the `data` attribute and bound to the `form-number` attribute, which also appears in the **HTML**.

### EDIT

`el: "#app"` is just a convention for the basic **Vue** app. You can choose where to mount the app by any valid selector - like `[myCustomAttribute="mounthere"]` also works.

Comment: I appreciate the people who take the time to help, unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for get data on el: #id but without id only from my custom attribute like el: 'myattribute'

Comment: @cehojo1341 - it starts to become clearer. So, you would like to mount your app on a custom attribute?

Comment: @cehojo1341 - modified the snippet so it is mounted on a custom attribute. Even removed the `el` from the app to a detached `$mount` function.